# How to apply an ExpiresDefault directive to a single file, excluding similar files in subdirectories in Apache 2.4

Tags: apache-2.4, configuration

I have to set Cache-Control max-age to 1 hour on the root index.html, but to 1 day for every other file on the site. So other index.html files in subdirectories must also use the usual 1 day expiration. Preferably in .htaccess configuration files.

This seems to be a trivial task, but until now I haven't found any solution. Even if I give up on .htaccess, I only have an awkward solution:

```
<Directories "/srv" >
    ExpiresDefault "access 1 days"
    <Files index.html>
        ExpiresDefault "access 1 hours"
    </Files>
</Directories>
<Directories "/srv/*" >
    ExpiresDefault "access 1 days"
</Directories>
```

This first set expiration to 1 days on every file, except index.html, than it overrides the expiration again to 1 days on every subdirectories.

Are there any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution using the "if" directive:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_FILENAME} == '%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/index.html'">
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 hours"
</If>
```

This works in .htaccess, but a bit awkward, because the right side of the condition must include the path to the .htaccess file, which should be implicit, equal to the directory containing the .htaccess.

Another solution, which only work in the central configuration file, not in .htaccess:

```
<DirectoryMatch "^/srv/www-example-com/[^/]*$">
    <Files "index.html">
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 hours"
    </Files>
</DirectoryMatch>
```

Note the strange ending of the regular expression. Apache compares the full URL path with the regular expression including the file name - instead of comparing only the directory name matching the URL! This is likely an Apache bug, my Apache version is 2.4.18 (Ubuntu 16.04). Usually this does not matter, because the intention is the match directories and subdirectories, therefore a prefix match is used, no $ at the end of the expression.

This behavior could be even useful, because DirectoryMatch could actually  match a specific file too. However that is not the case with index.html, because the URL of index.html can be both example.com/ and example.com/index.html, and occasionally maybe example.com without slash (if DirectorySlash is off).